# Can sed match one part of a line and replace another part, for multiple lines that each have a different match and replacement?

Tags: sed

Given a file containing multiple lines with this format:

```
define('SOME_NAME', some_value);
```

How can `sed` be used to match `SOME_NAME` and replace `some_value` with `some_other_value`, for multiple different lines ?

This is a solution for one line:

```
sed -re "s|^(define *\('SOME_NAME'\s*,\s*).*(\);)|\1 some_other_value \2|" defs_file
```

To process a number of similar definitions in a file, I had to script outside `sed` (this example uses a `bash` version 4 associative array):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A args
args=([SOME_NAME1]=some_other_value1
      [SOME_NAME2]=some_other_value2
      [SOME_NAME3]=some_other_value3
      [SOME_NAME4]=some_other_value4
      [SOME_NAME5]=some_other_value5)

for arg in "${!args[@]}"
do
  sed -i -re "s|^(define *\('$arg'\s*,\s*).*(\);)|\1 ${args[$arg]} \2|" defs_file
done
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this result that only relies on `sed` ?

Comment: Between "more elegant" and "only sed," I think you'll have to choose one for this. I'd probably use awk or perl.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/$/\n@NAME:new_value/;s/([^,]*),[^\n]*\n.*@\1:([^@]*).*/\1,\2/;P;d' <<<"NAME,old_value"
```

This is a simplified example of yours; appending a lookup to the pattern space and then using regexp and back references to match and rearrange the output. See [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/lookup_tables.txt) for a detailed explanation.

N.B. In the example above (for brevity) I only included one lookup, in a real solution the lookup table would have several e.g. `s/$/\n@NAME1:new_value1@NAME2:new_value2..../`